# How to submit iPhone app (with watch kit extension and watch app) to app store?

Tags: app-store, apple-watch

I'd like to know how the process differs from the existing iPhone app submission procedure, as by following the usual process leads to an error of invalid binary after the app gets successfully submitted to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your version or build number is not the same between your iPhone and watch app?  More information on the error you're getting would be helpful.

I assume you've read this: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest running through the tips listed here: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/4/2/submitting-your-watchkit-app